# howto iterate menu items in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I read wordpress code documents about how to iterate menu items, and then I wrote this code in index.php:

```
<?php
    $menu_name = 'top_menu';
    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_name);
    foreach ((array)$array_menu as $mol) ;
    {
        echo $mol;
    }
?>
```

But it doesn't work. And is returning nothing. Casting to array didn't help so.

I need to echo items menu title one by one. without any html list tags.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

**$navItem** is an object, so you can not just echo it, try to echo its properties like this:

```
foreach ($array_menu as $navItem ) {

    echo '<li><a href="'.$navItem->url.'" title="'.$navItem->title.'">'.$navItem->title.'</a></li>';

}
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. my code and also your code problem is in foreach line. it returns this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp01\wp-content\themes\test01\test01\index.php on line 46

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
<?php  
function get_menu_items_by_registered_slug($menu_slug) {
    $menu_items = array();
    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_slug ] ) ) {
        $menu = get_term( $locations[ $menu_slug ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    }
    return $menu_items;
}
$show_menus = [];
$menus = get_menu_items_by_registered_slug('primary');
foreach( $menus as $menu ) {
    $show_menus[] = $menu->title;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($show_menus);
?>
```